# Why static methods can't be used inside instance methods or constructor

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Here is the code:

```
class Foo {
    static m() {
        console.log('m');
    }
}
class Bar extends Foo { 
    b() {
        super.m();
    }
}

var b = new Bar();
b.b();
```

that throws:

```
Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value).m is not a function
```

This type of error is generated when I attempt to use parent class static methods in an instance method or a constructor. Why?

As I understand, `super` refers to the `Foo`, and the following works OK:

```
class Bar extends Foo { 
    b() {
        Foo.m();
    }
}
```

Comment: because `m` does not belong to an instance? `Foo.m();`

Comment: @Igor, please see my update

Comment: @Jonasw You don't create a new instance of foo. There's only one instance (`this`).

Comment: I think the correct question is why would you call a static method in non-static way if you are aware of differences between class and class instance

Comment: @Jonasw Sorry, I don't follow your example. But `super` is `Foo.prototype` in `Bar` instance methods.

Comment: @JanHruby, because I'm learning the details of the implemantion

Comment: @estus:Sorry, my confusion. i think its better if i dont use the new class syntax. I stay with prototype chaining...

Comment: @Jonasw Under the hood ES6 classes are mostly syntactic sugar and utilize the same prototype inheritance techniques that were widely used in ES5. You can recognize them easily by examining Typescript output, for example.

Comment: @estus i know. But the syntax is quite unfamilar for me, may i should have a deeper look into it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `super` properties refer to `Foo.prototype` properties in instance methods, and `super` properties refer to `Foo` static properties in static methods.

`super(...)` call in constructor has special meaning and does something like `Foo.call(this, ...)` internally.

`super` alone has no meaning and cannot be used as a regular variable.

It should be:

```
b() {
    this.constructor.m();
}
```

because `Bar` inherits `m` static method from `Foo`.

Or if it specifically should be parent class,

```
b() {
    super.constructor.m();
}
```

Comment: _Because super refers to prototype of parent class in instance methods_ - so does it refer to different things in `constructor` and `instance methods`? If so, what does it refer to in a `constructor`?

Comment: `super(...)` has special meaning and can be used only in constructor. `super` properties are `Foo.prototype` properties in instance methods and `Foo` properties in static methods. I would say that `super === super.constructor`, but `super` cannot be used alone.

Comment: thanks, can you please add this information to the answer, that's the key to answering my question. also, to clarify, does `super` without invocation operator have no meaning in a constructor? It seems to be the case as if I use it without invocation I get the `Uncaught SyntaxError: 'super' keyword unexpected here` error

Comment: Sure. No, it can't be used without a dot or `()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to examine an instance of `Foo`.
You will see that `m` is not a regular member of the `Foo` instance but it is "hooked" under the `constructor` as a public static method.

For you code to work, just change the `b` method definition on `Bar class` to:

```
b() {
    super.constructor.m();
}
```

More on this topic can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static

Comment: _You will see that m is not a regular member of the Foo instance_  - that's not true, see my example with `Foo.m();`

Comment: @Maximus `Foo` in not an instance of Foo. `var i = new Foo();` creates an instance `i` of `Foo` and when you try to call `i.m()` you get `TypeError: i.m is not a function`